# Why isn't the return statement executing? Binary Search

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search

The algorithm finds the result and tests for true but does not return de value and returns -2. Does anybody know why? I haven't been able to figure it out.
 Here is the code:

```
int recursiveBinarySearch(int* a, int p, int r, int x){

    if(p>r){
        return -1;
    }else{
        int m = (p+r)/2;
        cout<<(a[m]==x)<<endl;
        if(a[m]==x){
            cout<<"entering"<<endl;
            return (m+1);
            cout<<"wtf?"<<endl;
           }else if(x<a[m]){
               recursiveBinarySearch(a,p,m-1,x);
               }else if(x>a[m]) recursiveBinarySearch(a,m+1, r,x);

    }
    return -2;

}
```

Here is the output ($ := my input):

```
>>$./a.out
>>Type the number of slots
>>$100
>>Type a number to search for
>>$40
>>0
>>0
>>0
>>0
>>0
>>1
>>entering
>>The search did not return any item-2
```

Comment: Think about what your function returns if it enters one of the two recursive calls. Look at the code path once those recursive calls finish.

Comment: Your return statement isn't executing because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `recursiveBinarySearch( )` recursively, you call it with a `return` statement, because if the recursive function returns something, the function that calls the recursive function should return the same value.

The code should be:

```
int recursiveBinarySearch(int* a, int p, int r, int x)
{
if(p>r)
    return -1;
else
{
    int m = (p+r)/2;
    cout<<(a[m]==x)<<endl;
    if(a[m]==x)
    {
        cout<<"entering"<<endl;
        return (m+1);
        cout<<"wtf?"<<endl;
    }
    else if(x<a[m])
      //Added a return statement to both the recurring function call.
    return recursiveBinarySearch(a,p,m-1,x);
    else if(x>a[m]) 
      //Added a return statement to both the recurring function call.
    return recursiveBinarySearch(a,m+1, r,x);
}
return -2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `recursiveBinarySearch` is ignored in the recursion try writing:

```
return recursiveBinarySearch(a,p,m-1,x);
```