# the return value is different from the value calculated in the function

Tags: c++, return

The return value should be 7 and is calculated correctly in the gcd function.
So I return the value in line 7.

But in the main function, when i printed out the return value, it is 3.
I don't know why.

```
int gcd(int p, int q) 

 {

    if(p<q){gcd(q,p);}
    if(q==0)
    {
        cout<<"p: "<<p<<endl; //This prints out 7
        return p;
    }
    else gcd(q,p%q);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    int count=0;
    cin>>n;
    while(n--)
    {
    count++;
    cout<<"Pair #"<<count<<": ";
    string input,input2;
    cin>>input>>input2;
    int sum1=0,sum2=0;
    int g;      
    for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
    {
        if(input[i]-'0'==1)
            sum1+=pow(2,input.size()-1-i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<input2.size();i++)
    {
        if(input2[i]-'0'==1)
            sum2+=pow(2,input2.size()-1-i);
    }
    cout<<sum1<<" "<<sum2<<endl;
    g = gcd(sum1,sum2);
    cout<<"g: "<<g<<endl; //but this print out 3

  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `return` at line 11

Comment: Although everything else posted here is `C` compatible, `cout`  & `cin` are exclusively `C++`

Comment: *"The return value should be 7"* For what values of `input1` and `input2` would that be? Also, please explain what the `gcd()` function is supposed to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't the return statement executing? Binary Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007532/why-isnt-the-return-statement-executing-binary-search)

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions, including how calling a function does not automagically and immediately return the result of that function call.

You need to return a value on every execution path or your code will have undefined behaviour;

```
int gcd(int p, int q) 
{
    if (p < q)
    {
        return gcd(q, p);
    }
    if (q == 0)
    {
        cout << "p: " << p << endl;
        return p;
    }
    else 
        return gcd(q, p % q);
}
```

(A decent compiler should be able to warn you about those missing `return`s. Find out how to enable such warnings.)